# problems to load interbase and firebird library

Tags: php, xampp, firebird, interbase

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase' (tried: 
C:\xampp\php\ext\interbase (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.), 
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.)) in Unknown on line 
0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\interbase 
(Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll (Impossibile 
trovare il 
modulo specificato.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'firebird' (tried: 
C:\xampp\php\ext\firebird 
(Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_firebird.dll (Impossibile trovare 
il 
modulo specificato.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'firebird' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\firebird 
(Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_firebird.dll (Impossibile trovare 
il 
modulo specificato.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to change the names and to paste the fbclient.dll into apache and php path but nothing append, what's the problem?

Comment: Make sure you use the correct DLL, If your PHP is 32bit the DLL needs to be 32bit as well. If your PHP is 64bit the DLL needs to be 64bit.

Comment: 1) Make PHP return errors in English, probably by setting LOCALE environment variable or something else, that should be told in PHP manual how to override languages. I do not know what "Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato." stand for. 2) use tools like SysInternals Process Monitor to see which DLL files PHP process looks for and in which folders. That may possible been that PHP process tries to load DLL1 which is statically linked to DLL2, then if DLL2 is not found the DLL1 won't be loaded and would be mentioned in the error text.

Comment: It is not looking for fbclient.dll, it is looking for php_interbase.dll or php_firebird.dll. Do you have those libraries? (and no, it is not a renamed fbclient.dll).

Comment: Yes I have those libraries but I changed the database to mysql now